# Missing network-manager after uninstalling lightdm from debian buster 10.7

Tags: debian, networking, apt, networkmanager

I'm running Debian buster 10.7 with i3 window manager on a i686 arch personal pc. Just for the sake of experimentation, I did `apt remove lightdm`, and thought that it would be fine with just a tty login prompt rather than default lightdm. When I typed in `apt remove lightdm`, it also showed a bunch of packages that said are no longer needed and could be removed with `apt autoremove`. So I went with it, I did `apt remove lightdm && apt autoremove`, and then I noticed while autoremove was complete, it also uninstalled `network-manager`. At first glance, I thought it deleted a previous version of network manager since I updated the system yesterday. I went along and did a reboot. Then plugged in my cable, and there was no internet. I tried my phone's tethering as well, which I frequently use for net browsing and such. Now I'm left with an offline pc. I did `ip addr`, and it shows my cord is connected, but no ipv4 address is shown, which usually did before.

I did as root `systemctl start NetworkManager`, and it said, it was masked. I did `systemctl status NetworkManager`, it says dead service. I did `systemctl unmask NetworkManager.service`, and then `systemctl start NetworkManager` now it says no service NetworkManager.service found.

I'm failry a noob. What can I do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to get an Internet connection: connect your Ethernet cable, use `ip link` to display your interfaces network (e,g: `enp2s0` interface and `192.168.0.1` gatway), then run the follwoing command:

```
sudo ip link set enp2s0 up 
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.100/24 dev enp2s0
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

then you will be able to install the missnig packages through `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager
```

Comment: Unfortunately, isn't working for me. I ran `ip a` and got 3 interfaces, lo, enp2s0 and enp0s29f7u1. I tried what you suggested, just replacing eth0 with enp0s29f7u1. Network excahnges seems to be null, if I ran tcpdump.

Comment: Two options popped in my head. If I ran apt install network-manager, the list of packages that shows up as dependencies, I could manually download them from deb.debian.org/debian/ and place them and then finally download and install network-manager.deb and install it, or the second option is to reinstall the whole os.

Comment: @honeymoly could you run `sudo dhclient enp2s0` let's see the results.

Comment: Hey @GAD3R, I manually downloaded all the 5 *.deb packages from https://deb.debian.org/debian/ and did `dpkg -i *` to install all the deb pacakages. I can access the internet and am writing this from my pc. Also, in the process of removing lightdm(which autoremoved 218 MB of space), I also noticed that, notify-send also doesn't work for some odd reason. I'm thinking of backing up everything and reinstalling debian. Startx seems to have issues as well.

Comment: The debian I'm using came with xfce4 desktop environment. If I logged into xfce DE at first, `notify-send` works fine, however, if I log in to i3 window manager after boot, `notify-send` doesn't work. It used to prior to deleting `lightdm` and `apt autoremove`. But here's the fun part, if I logged into xfce, then log out, and log back in to i3, notify-send wroks then.

Comment: I think I messed up some important packages in the process of removing with `apt autoremove`.

Comment: Thanks, and after doing the above I still didn't have DNS resolution and had to run `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` to get that working.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved my issue was to first check which packages/dependencies debian pulls for the required **network-manager** package. So, I issued this on the terminal as a root user;

`apt show network-manager`

This will show the necessary libraries under **depends** subtitle. Next run;

`apt install network-manager -y`

Although you should be offline at this point, but debian will list out the url's at this point with the package names on your terminal. This will be something like

`failed to fetch https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main network-manager_14.0.5-amd64.deb`

Go ahead and download the required package which shows up after `failed` and the url. For example, to download the network-manager from the previous link, you'd have to go to your browser, then type in

`https://deb.debian.org/debian/main/pool/n/network-manager`

then download the package from there from another device which has internet access and place all the *.deb pakcages in your debian pc.Then to install them, just type in `dpkg -i "your-package-name.deb"`. If you happen to place all the *.deb packages under same directory, you can install all of them with `dpkg -i *`.

I'm sure this is not a proper way to solve the issue, especially incase you don't happen to have another device with internet access. But I got lucky. Hopefully someone comes up with a proper solution. It's still weird to me that running `apt remove lightdm && apt autoremove` removed a whole bunch of packages, might I add essential ones such as network-manager.